# Flutter decode error --"flutter: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' has no instance method 'decode'."

Tags: flutter

I trying to decode a string and I get the following error

flutter: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, String>' has no instance method 'decode'.
decode("{"response_id":"6c9dc8c9","replies":[{"text":"Great!"},{"text":"Are you authorized to work lawfully in the United States without employer sponsorship?"},{"qs":[{"text":"Yes","payload":"__yes"},{"text":"No","payload":"__no"}]}],"state":"IN_PROGRESS","language":"en","undo_available":true,"performance_metrics":{"total_time":446,"time_get_state":35,"time_logic":276,"time_store_state":92,"time_notifications":42}}")

Here a snippet of my code

```
static getReply(var json) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": "Bearer $TKN",
    };
    var body = jsonEncode(json);
    var response = await http.post(
      RCE_REPLY_URL,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: body,
    );
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
      throw Exception('Invalid');
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);  //error thrown
      return jsonData;
    }
  }
```

Can you please give me some hint and how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe that's because of your Collision between Function Parameter and Package Name. 
Because both are the same name `json`.

 Try something like this,

```
static getReply(var data) async {
    Map<String, String> requestHeaders = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      "Authorization": "Bearer $TKN",
    };
    var body = jsonEncode(data);
    var response = await http.post(
      RCE_REPLY_URL,
      headers: requestHeaders,
      body: body,
    );
    final int statusCode = response.statusCode;
    if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400) {
      throw Exception('Invalid');
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);  
      return jsonData;
    }
  }
```

Hope that solves your issue!

> **Tip:** You can use `jsonDecode`, a shorthand for json.decode. Useful if a local variable shadows the global [json] constant.

Further Reference: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.1/dart-convert/jsonDecode.html